# Overflow screen frozen in iOS10

Tags: css, cordova, intel-xdk

I have one div inside another div. the outer div includes these two css lines:

```
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

The inner div is much longer than the screen display can allow, so my inner div css does not include:

```
    height: calc(100% + 1px);
```

That said, I have tested this, and adding this does not help.

In iOS9, the my inner div scrolls as expected and I see a scroll bar (both what I want).

In iOS10, no scroll bar. What is way worse than that is the inner div does not scroll at all, meaning all the information contained (but invisible because hidden) is not accessible at all.

Question: how to fix no scroll and frozen screen on overflow-y constrained dives in iOS10?